# Add a caption to an image

Tags: macos, image-editing

Need a simple program to add captions to lots of images (Several 1000 - for a hobby website).  Some will have the same caption, so copy and paste are a requirement, but may need background colour changes, depending on image colours in the caption placement area.

I use OSX 10.9.5 and I have tried Preview, but it does not have the facility to style text, BOLD and Italic.

I am looking for a solution, in which I can quickly make these captions.

I have Affinity Designer and Inkscape and Pixelmator, which can do this but they are very much overkill, for a relatively simple task.  Preview would be fine if it met my requirements.

Annotate would appear to have done what I want, but it needs a newer version of OSX and Napkin seems a bit expensive for what I need.

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: Aren't OSX upgrades free, so why not upgrade and use Annotate?

Comment: As another idea, why not add annotations on the website instead of for the images?

Comment: Very fearful of upgrading.  I just know there will be changes and upgrades needed, that I may not be able to resolve and everything else i do works fine.  Recently upgraded phone and had all sorts of problems.  In 50 years of computing - I have never experienced a hassle free upgrade.   Re annotations on website, I wish to retain the caption with the image and although I could add it to IPTC, that requires software to show it, whereas if it is on the surface of the image, it is always visible.  Thanks for ideas

Answer (score 1):

I worked out a solution - while not as efficient, as I would have liked it does work.

I used my Affinity Designer to create a template caption image.  I edit the text on that and then COPY that to the clipboard.  I have several templates, for various sized images and orientation.

Select all similar images and open in Preview.

Select All for each image (otherwise Paste does not work) and then Paste 'caption' from clipboard and position on the image.  Repeat for each image and then Save All.